# How to add external GUI libraries to NetBeans Palette?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, material-ui

I'm trying to add this library https://github.com/atarw/material-ui-swing to my NetBeans Palette to use the JButtons. I've tried adding the maven reference to pom.xml and adding the Palette manually, but this did not worked. What can I do to create a project using these designs? (Do I have to use another IDE?)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add any additional component to the Netbinse because material-ui-swing doesn't have any new.

The focus of the library is to work with the basic swing component to help old applications modernize the look.

Of curse, under the organization https://github.com/material-ui-swing there are additional new components like snack bar and other JtextField tools as an experiment, and you can add this component to Netbeans as normal procedure because they are JComponent :)

P.S: I'm the author of the evolution in the last few years of materia-ui-swing